# gcc version 4.1.2 in mac os x

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, macos

I am taking a programming class and we are required to use the gcc 4.1.2 compiler to compile our c++ projects. I will be creating my projects in xcode and can't find how to set that compiler. I went to the get info window on the project and hit the drop down under Compiler Version, however I do not have 4.1.2 on the list. It seems that this compiler is not installed on my computer. Does anybody know where I can download it and how I can set it as my system default gcc compiler for the term?

Comment: Since a class with such a requirement is probably not mac-programming-specific, a lazy approach to the problem is to use VirtualBox and install an old Ubuntu/Kubuntu 7.04 "Feisty Fawn"...it shipped with gcc 4.1.2 as the default.  Personally, I like to do work in virtual machines whenever possible, especially if I'm doing tweaks to the system environment.

Comment: I could achieve that same thing by remote desktop-ing into the university's linux machines. I prefer doing my projects locally on my computer only doing final testing on their environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably get away with using whatever version of GCC is on your Mac, and doing a final compile on the university machines as a check.  In general, the user visible changes using a later version is stricter syntax checking, so you might do something on the Mac that won't pass a newer compiler, but that generally isn't too common.  I haven't had to change more than a few lines on our 50k line codebase.

Comment: This is a more advanced course then the previous ones I have taken. In my previous courses I did precisely that, and never had to change any code from my computer to their environment. However, because this is a more complex course, I wanted to try and get the same compiler version to minimize potential issues I may run into while rushing to complete a project.

Answer (score 2):

With the current developer tools, only gcc 4.0 and 4.2 are available. You could probably get gcc 4.1.2 via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), however, I'm not sure whether you can integrate it into XCode.

Before you try this, you should maybe first check with the class instructor whether it is really necessary to use **exactly** 4.1.2, or if it is OK to use 4.0 resp. 4.2 instead.